# How to set text value to translate using api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, translate

I want to make a simple application that translates English into Yodish, but I have no idea how to indicate the value of my text box.

I'm trying to get to the data text properties. I manage how to replace the text in the proper field but I'm still getting the initial value instead of the current one.

This is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LoXe.jpg

More precisely I do it like this:

```
"data": { text: $("#input").val() }
```

I want to achieve this effect: https://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/
Here is the data content: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmzSu.jpg

```js
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://yodish.p.rapidapi.com/yoda.json?text=Master%20Obiwan%20has%20lost%20a%20planet.",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "yodish.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "...",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    text: $("#input").val()
  }
}

$("#button").click(function() {
  $.getJSON(settings).done(function(data) {
    $("#result").text(data.contents.translated);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="translator">
  <input type="text" id="input" value="Obi wan">
  <button id="button">Convert to Yoda-Speak!</button>
  <textarea id="result"> Asdasdas.  Herh herh herh.</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are sending a POST request why do you have a GET parameter for text in the  URL? `https://yodish.p.rapidapi.com/yoda.json?text=Master%20Obiwan...`

Comment: @ArleighHix To be honest, I have been learning javascript for a short time and I used the data that I got at: https://rapidapi.com/orthosie/api/yoda-translator in general, everything works fine, except that I can't correctly select the text to be translated

Comment: Oh, see I now do! My answer you must check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is where/when you define the value of `settings` you need to do this inside the click function in order to get the current value of the input (see snippet). This is why you are always getting the initial value, because you read it before it gets changed.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://yodish.p.rapidapi.com/yoda.json",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "yodish.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "...",
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "data": {
      text: $("#input").val()
    }
  }
  $.getJSON(settings).done(function(data) {
    $("#result").text(data.contents.translated);
  })
  console.log(settings.data)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="translator">
  <input type="text" id="input" value="Obi wan">
  <button id="button">Convert to Yoda-Speak!</button>
  <textarea id="result"> Asdasdas.  Herh herh herh.</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You are great, thank you so much.
I spent a lot of time on it and it turns out to be so simple.